# RightBarButtonItem not showing up, when leftBarButtonItem works fine

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

In my app I have a push segue from `HomeViewController` to `EditProfileViewController` which should have a back button as a `leftBarItem` and a settings cog as a `rightBarItem`. The back button displays normally, but the right item is missing. These `ViewControllers` live happen in the `MainNavigationController` which has a Navigation Bar.

I tried to define the `rightBarButton` in `ViewDidLoad` of the `EditProfileVC`, I also tried to have a `rightBarItem` in the storyboard for the View controller.

```
    let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: settingsIcon, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(settingsPressed))
    buttonItem.tintColor = UIColor(.settingsIconTint)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem
```

Interestingly if I change the rightBar to a leftBar item, the back button is replaced with the settings cog and works as I expect, but I can't go back to the main page.

```
    let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: settingsIcon, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(settingsPressed))
    buttonItem.tintColor = UIColor(.settingsIconTint)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem
```

Comment: You need to manually pop it if you're replacing the default back button.

Comment: I don't wanna replace the default back button. I just want to have a rightBarItem alongside the default back button

Comment: If you want to have both the back button and left buttons use this`self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true`, but since you cannot add a right item that means something else is missing, coz your code is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set a `rightBarButtonItem` in a `navigationBar`,

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func openEditVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditProfileViewController") as? EditProfileViewController {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

class EditProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Settings", style: .plain, target: self, action:  #selector(settingsPressed))
        buttonItem.tintColor = .red
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem
    }

    @objc func settingsPressed() {
        print("Setting Pressed")
    }
}
```

In the above code I've added a `UIBarButtonItem` with `title` `Settings` as a `rightBarButtonItem` of `navigationBar`.

No need to configure `leftBarButtonItem` it not required. `Back button` is added by default.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

In case it doesn't satisfy your requirement, add a screenshot of what is expected so I can help.

Comment: The `leftBarButtonItem` is working fine as a default back button. It's the `rightBarButtonItem` I want to set as `buttonItem`. Anyway I tried to append `buttonItem` into the `rightBarButtonItems` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Thank you, moving the code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear` fixed it